# How to use Zurb Foundation 3 in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, zurb-foundation

I am starting to learn Rails and have created a new 3.2.8 project where I want to include the Zurb Foundation framework and want to make it as easy as possible to update (patches and new "features") the framework going forward - which, I guess?, would be best done with a 'gem install xx' now and then 'gem update' further down the road.

Stumbled upon https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails (which is for Foundation 2) where it is stated that "The current zurb-foundation gem is now hosted at: https://github.com/zurb/foundation" - but I can't seem to find a gem for Foundation 3 there.

Sorry if this is a novice question, but I guess we all have to start somewhere :-)

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.html

Normally I wouldn't do this, but since this keeps disappearing in history of 404s, I'll paste some of it here.  This is current as of Foundation 4 (3/1/2013):

### Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  # Add Foundation Here
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
end
```

then

```
$bundle install
```

### Easy install:

```
rails g foundation:install
```

### Manual install:

#### app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "foundation";
```

#### app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require foundation
```

#### my_layout.html.erb

```
<head>
    <!--Add to your head inside your page layout-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Zurb Foundation install guide for Rails 3 here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/rails.html

Comment: This should have been the correct answer, the other one is now a 404 error.